# Storage Limit in Truss-supported Attic?

Tags: roof, attic, storage

I recently purchased a home that has access to what appears to be somewhat usable attic space. There's a 2x2 foot hatch in one of our upstairs closets that grants (not so convenient) access. In the attic, there is an 8x8 area with plywood laid over the floorboards. The whole space is supported by a truss system, spanned every 24 inches along. Here's a picture of it, with a few things stored.

[image]

So here's my question - I know not to mess with the truss system but I'm wondering how much that 8x8 space can support? I'm not gonna put anything crazy up there, but am I good to put 1-2 dozen boxes (clothes, Christmas stuff, etc.) on those boards without compromising anything? There are some load bearing walls underneath the 8x8 area as well so it feels solid to walk on. Thoughts on the usability of the space?

Comment: Very light storage would likely be OK, but it is an invitation to overload. If it is a truss AFIK the load is carried at the ends. No load bearing walls under middle of trusss, only partition walls. As seasons change and temperatures change the bottom cords of trusses will sometimes lift up above parition walls. Loading by storage would inhibit that. As trusses crossing top plates of partition walls are supposed to be restrained by a slotted metal fitting which restricts lateral movement but allows vertical movement in a limited range.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Jim! I didn't know that about load bearing walls under trusses - I guess that was a false assumption. Good to know about the light storage too - I know I don't want to overdo it, but I was just wondering how concerned to be. There is a light and those 8x8 planks up there for a reason, I suppose, but not sure exactly how the space was used before us!

Comment: The 2x2' hatch in a closet is a tip-off that the bullder did not design this space for any use other than access to wiring or other maintenance, IMHO. No water heater, HVAC in attic, right? Our 1970 tract house is built this way (water heater, furnace in closet in hallway, somewhat noisy for us but our HVAC service loves it) although our 2'x2' hatch is in the integral garage next to the common wall. I use a ladder for access. Ours is a low pitch (3-in-12) and we never considered it for storage in 45 years. Many people would put in pull down stairs (in garage if possible)

Comment: If the plywood is cut into 2 ft wide strips, that is a tip-off it was put in after the house was  built. One would hope that whoever put it there did not pinch any wires between the plywood and the truss cords/ceiling joists.

Comment: If you put heavier stuff close to the edges where the truss web members connect to the bottom chords, that should minimize the extra demand on the trusses.

Comment: My trusses carry the weight of my heat pump air handler.  In fairness, the platform is located just to one side of (above) an interior wall, so that probably helps support it a bit.

Comment: Thanks Jim - very informative additions. No there is basically nothing up there except some piping and ventilation for bathroom fans. I do agree that the small and frankly inconvenient access point doesn't bode well for its use as storage, although there is a light up there and the plywood appears to be uncut (8x4') so it must have been installed during construction. Advice below seems to be 10 pounds per foot at minimum so maybe I stick with that to be conservative.

Answer (score 2):

Under [IRC R301.5](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-3-building-planning#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch03_SecR301.5) it's probably designed for 10 psf live load, where that live load is considered an allowance for work, not storage. For 8 ft squared, then, that's 640# capacity including you when you're messing with stuff up there.

From the table under [IRC R301.5](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-3-building-planning#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch03_SecR301.5), your attic either fits into "uninhabitable attics without storage" (10 psf live load) or it fits into "uninhabitable attics with limited storage" (20 psf live load, including storage). To qualify for the 20 psf, footnote `g` prescribes:

> Uninhabitable attics with limited storage are those where the clear height between joists and rafters is 42 inches or greater, or where there are two or more adjacent trusses with web configurations capable of accommodating an assumed rectangle 42 inches in height by 24 inches in width, or greater, within the plane of the trusses.
>
> The live load need only be applied to those portions of the joists or truss bottom chords where all of the following conditions are met:
>
> 1. The attic area is accessed from an opening not less than 20 inches in width by 30 inches in length that is located where the clear height in the attic is not less than 30 inches.
> 2. The slopes of the joists or truss bottom chords are not greater than 2 units vertical in 12 units horizontal.
> 3. Required insulation depth is less than the joist or truss bottom chord member depth.
>
> The remaining portions of the joists or truss bottom chords shall be designed for a uniformly distributed concurrent live load of not less than 10 pounds per square foot.

Your access hatch doesn't meet the 1st condition. It's quite possible that your required insulation depth is greater than the bottom chord depth, violating the 3rd condition. Under the IRC, then, your attic would be only good for the 10 psf live load.

Comment: Wow, what a helpful response. Thank you! So 10 lbs per square foot is a safe conservative assumption - that's really all I'll probably need anyway with light overflow storage. I will say that my attic entrance is really more like the standard 20x30 size so that probably fits the bill, but not sure about the insulation requirement situation. Sounding unlikely that it's designed for more than 10 lbs/foot.

Comment: @Adam, you can trust it for 10 psf. I see about 9 ft between your truss panel points. The typical #2 grade 2x4s that truss manufacturers like to use (at your 24" centers) are only good for about a 9.5 ft span between panel points under 10 psf (about a 7 ft span between panel points under 20 psf). See the tables under https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-8-roof-ceiling-construction#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch08_SecR802.5.1 for 2x4 spans if you're interested. This supports the theory that your trusses were designed for only 10 psf.

Comment: thanks for the additional confirmation. Super helpful! Your assessment sounds solid and I'll be sure to limit my storage up there to a few hundred pounds. That'll be enough to free up some garage space but probably not enough to justify investing in a separate attic entrance or anything like that (since I'll only use it a few times yearly if it's not a great space for storage). Really appreciate it!

Comment: One other question for you if you're still lurking in this thread! I was discussing this with an engineer buddy of mine tonight, and he seemed to think that the fact that the 8x8 storage space is pretty much centered above a dividing wall that divides two bedrooms below (which runs perpendicular to the trusses) should significantly add to the support/deflection of the weight. Any thoughts on that? I've heard mixed things about whether a truss system draws any benefit from the walls below them.

Comment: @Adam, I think it's probably a regional thing. There's an ecosystem of products for decoupling trusses from partition walls, e.g. https://www.strongtie.com/trussclips_platedtrussconnectors/tc_roofclips/p/stc.stct.dtc. The age of the construction would be a relevant factor, where older trusses would probably be resting on your wall. For newer stuff, I suspect that bearing on the walls is a function of the region's humidity and roof load variability (I'm thinking snow).

Comment: @Adam, in unconditioned attics the truss moisture content follows seasonal humidity, where lots of seasonal variation implies that the truss members get longer and shorter, in turn causing the truss to move up and down. For conditioned attics under the relatively new practice of spray foam on the underside of roof sheathing, seasonal variation probably moves the truss more because only the top chord is subjected to the exterior humidity.

Comment: @Adam, my expectation is that homes in regions with high humidity variability or high roof load variability have a higher frequency of drywall damage from the movement, where building officials have reactively demanded decoupling of trusses from interior walls. Go to the end of your platform and check to see if there's a gap between the bottom chord and the wall's top plate. Even if there's no gap at the moment, there could theoretically be a product like https://www.strongtie.com/strongdrive_interiorwoodscrews/sdpw_screw/p/strong-drive-sdpw-deflector-screw in there, so it's still not certain.

Comment: Helpful as always, @popham! I'll need to see what kind of a view I can get showing the gap between the truss and wall below and see if I can learn anything definitive. What should the takeaway be based on whether it's resting or separate from the wall? Would resting indicate more potential storage ability or no?

Answer (score 1):

Most code-compliant modern attic trusses will do 20 lbs/square foot as the design load, unless they are specifically designed & made as spare room or storage trusses with greater loading.

That load includes the weight of the insulation, drywall and plywood, not "in excess of those." So you'll need to subtract ~1 PSF for drywall, perhaps another pound for plywood and a bit for insulation, depending on how thick that is so probably less than 18 but more than 17, in most cases.

Comment: Interesting - thank you! I think I need to look into this more with my Township and see if they have records of some of these things. I'm curious - what would be considered "modern" in this case? The house was built in 1989 in PA.

Comment: Assuming #2 grade lumber and local species, the tables under https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-8-roof-ceiling-construction#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch08_SecR802.5.1 provide maximum span lengths for the bottom chord segments between panel points under 10 psf LL versus 20 psf LL. There's bending stress from the storage interacting with the truss member axial stresses, so the actual maximum span between panel points will be less than the tabulated maximum values.

Comment: Thanks for the additional clarity, @popham! 10 psf it is!